# How can I create a dictionary/hashmap within a map function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I wish to do this:

```
const ret = [];
nums.forEach(num => {
            const dict = [];
            dict[num] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            ret.push(dict);
        });
```

where `nums = ["const_0", "const_1"]` => `ret = [{const_0: random_number}, {const_1: random_number}]`.

I want to do this using the map function, for no better reason other than practice using map functions. Here's my current attempt:

```
let ret = [];
ret = nums.map( x => new Object()[x] = Math.random() * 2 - 1);
```

but this returns `ret = [random_number, random_number]`, it fails to create the dictionary/Object.

Comment: Array.prototype.map will always return an array.

Comment: If you want to return an object from an array function, you may be wanting Array.prototype.reduce, which can be used to build a single object via iterating over the array.

Comment: Was trying to figure out how to create a dictionary from an array and found out the way to do so is reduce, as Dan Oswalt mentioned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
const res = nums.map(x => ({[x]: Math.random() * 2 - 1}));
```

which is just a shorthand to

```js
const res = nums.map(x => {
    return {
        [x]:  Math.random() * 2 - 1
    };
});
```

Comment: Yes, object literal is a great answer!

Answer (score 0):

In this case I believe you need to assign the object to a variable and return the variable. new Object() runs the constructor method but I don't think it returns a value? Not sure. But this should work:

```
(x) => {
  let holder = {} // or new Object()
  holder[x] = calculation
  return holder
}
```

(I know, it's not nearly as pretty as your one-liner)

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple empty object literal and use bracket notation to assign each key.

```js
const keys = ['key1', 'key2'];

const result = keys.map(key => {
  let obj = {};
  obj[key] = (Math.random() * 2) - 1;
  return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```